# How to extract the Root CA and Subordinate CA from a certificate chain in Linux?

Tags: openssl, ssl, certificates

I have an end-entity/server certificate which have an intermediate and root certificate. When I `cat` on the end-entity certificate, I see only a single `BEGIN` and `END` tag. It is the only the end-entity certificate.

Is there any way I can view the intermediate and root certificate content. I need only the content of `BEGIN` and `END` tag.

In Windows I can see the full cert chain from the "Certification Path". Below is the example for the Stack Exchange's certificate.

[image]

From there I can perform a *View Certificate* and export them. I can do that for both root and intermediate in Windows. I am looking for this same method in Linux.

[image]

Comment: Please do tell us who issued you that cert.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro Let's say anyone... I want to see the cert chain for stackexchange with only the primary certificate in hand.

Answer (score 89, accepted):

From a web site, you can do:

```
openssl s_client -showcerts -verify 5 -connect stackexchange.com:443 < /dev/null
```

That will show the certificate chain and all the certificates the server presented.

Now, if I save those two certificates to files, I can use `openssl verify`:

```
$ openssl verify -show_chain -untrusted dc-sha2.crt se.crt 
se.crt: OK
Chain:
depth=0: C = US, ST = NY, L = New York, O = "Stack Exchange, Inc.", CN = *.stackexchange.com (untrusted)
depth=1: C = US, O = DigiCert Inc, OU = www.digicert.com, CN = DigiCert SHA2 High Assurance Server CA (untrusted)
depth=2: C = US, O = DigiCert Inc, OU = www.digicert.com, CN = DigiCert High Assurance EV Root CA
```

The `-untrusted` option is used to give the intermediate certificate(s); `se.crt` is the certificate to verify. The depth=2 result came from the system trusted CA store.

If you don't have the intermediate certificate(s), you can't perform the verify. That's just how X.509 works.

Depending on the certificate, it may contain a URI to get the intermediate from. As an example, `openssl x509 -in se.crt -noout -text` contains:

```
        Authority Information Access: 
            OCSP - URI:http://ocsp.digicert.com
            CA Issuers - URI:http://cacerts.digicert.com/DigiCertSHA2HighAssuranceServerCA.crt
```

That "CA Issuers" URI points to the intermediate cert (in DER format, so you need to use `openssl x509 -inform der -in DigiCertSHA2HighAssuranceServerCA.crt -out DigiCertSHA2HighAssuranceServerCA.pem` to convert it for further use by OpenSSL).

If you run `openssl x509 -in /tmp/DigiCertSHA2HighAssuranceServerCA.pem -noout -issuer_hash` you get `244b5494`, which you can look for in the system root CA store at `/etc/ssl/certs/244b5494.0` (just append `.0` to the name).

I don't think there is a nice, easy OpenSSL command to do all that for you.

Comment: That's the main problem. I don't have the URL with me. I only have the certificate file. And I need the encrypted content between `BEGIN` and `END` tag (which you will get after just `cat`ing the .crt file.

Comment: @AnirbanNag'tintinmj' If you're just looking to decode the certificate, try `openssl x509 -in file.crt -noout -text`

Comment: I want the content of intermediate at root cert which is between the `BEGIN` and `END` tag.

Comment: Or if you can give a command which will extract the intermediate and root cert from the primary cert and save that into a file... I can live with that too.

Comment: @AnirbanNag'tintinmj' If it's not showing up with the `openssl x509` command, I don't think the intermediate certificate is there. (Unless you got some error from `openssl x509`).

Comment: With `openssl x509` command the whole chain is showing up. I need to extract that... and the intermediate certificate is there. You can try with the stackexchange certificate.

Comment: @AnirbanNag'tintinmj' if you take off that `-noout` it should output all the certificates (I'm not sure what SE certificate file you're using; could you post it?)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59573/discussion-between-anirban-nag-tintinmj-and-derobert).

Comment: And failing all this, you go to the Digicert page, in the case of StackExchange, you double check them with the browser certs properties and have there at hand the intermediate and root certs.

Comment: Also see [How to split a PEM file](https://serverfault.com/q/391396/145545) on Server Fault, [How to view all SSL certificates in a bundle?](https://serverfault.com/a/591263/145545) on Ubuntu.SE, [How can I split a CA certificate bundle into separate files?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23644473/608639), etc.

Answer (score 79):

tl;dr - one liner bash magic to dump all certs in the chain

```
openssl s_client -showcerts -verify 5 -connect wikipedia.org:443 < /dev/null |
   awk '/BEGIN CERTIFICATE/,/END CERTIFICATE/{ if(/BEGIN CERTIFICATE/){a++}; out="cert"a".pem"; print >out}'
for cert in *.pem; do 
        newname=$(openssl x509 -noout -subject -in $cert | sed -nE 's/.*CN ?= ?(.*)/\1/; s/[ ,.*]/_/g; s/__/_/g; s/_-_/-/; s/^_//g;p' | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]').pem
        echo "${newname}"; mv "${cert}" "${newname}" 
done
```

*Explanation in 2 steps*

To dump all certs in the chain to the current dir as `cert${chain_number}.pem`:

```
openssl s_client -showcerts -verify 5 -connect your_host:443 < /dev/null |
 awk '/BEGIN CERTIFICATE/,/END CERTIFICATE/{ if(/BEGIN CERTIFICATE/){a++}; out="cert"a".pem"; print >out}'
```

The bonus-track to rename them to their common name:

```
for cert in *.pem; do 
   newname=$(openssl x509 -noout -subject -in $cert | sed -nE 's/.*CN ?= ?(.*)/\1/; s/[ ,.*]/_/g; s/__/_/g; s/_-_/-/; s/^_//g;p' | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]').pem
   mv $cert $newname 
done
```

Comment: Is there any reason to choose ".pem" versus ".crt" as the extension since you're only renaming them, not changing the format?

Comment: No, not really. ".pem" is the format (base64 of the DER) ".crt" means it's a certificate but doesn't tell anything about the encoding. I was about to make it more consistent and name all pem... But I think is simpler to read in the one liner to understand where the certificate is getting downloaded (crt) and finish what I typically use in the Linux world (pem). Hope this clarifies things a bit...

Comment: Yes it does, I realize PEM is a format but I often see crt and wasn't sure if it was a format. This actually helps explain why I see "crt" used so often. Thanks :)

Comment: This seems to only work if you already trust the source. I'm trying to download a custom CA but it's only downloading the first certificate, not the chain.

Comment: @mjaggard strange since I used it exactly for that case. That being said, the server might not be sending the root CA at all, if you take a look at my example, it used to download 3 certs now it's downloading only 2. I assume wikipedia server is not sending the root (there's really no point, if you don't have it, you won't trust it anyways...). I'm pretty sure it wasn't the case before.

Comment: `openssl s_client -showcerts -verify 5 -connect stackexchange.com:443 < /dev/null` doesn't show the root cert, only the intermediate and server cert

Comment: This blows up on certs without a Subject (ie. using Subject Alternative Name)

Comment: @shuckc If your certs do not have a subject (not very common, though valid), then don't rename them. Just use the first step and you should get the certs in the chain order. The first steep should work even without a common name.

Comment: The awk expression somehow generates incomplete files for cert2.pem and beyond (the files don't go all the way until END CERTIFICATE). The reason is that two of the certificates in my output contain the `END` string! The fix is to just specify `END CERTIFICATE` (and also `BEGIN CERTIFICATE` ) in the awk expression.

Comment: Like this: ```openssl s_client -showcerts -verify 5 -connect data.api.oneatlas.airbus.com:443 < /dev/null | awk '/BEGIN CERTIFICATE/,/END CERTIFICATE/{ if(/BEGIN/){a++}; out="cert"a".pem"; print >out}'; for cert in *.pem; do newname=$(openssl x509 -noout -subject -in $cert | sed -nE 's/.*CN ?= ?(.*)/\1/; s/[ ,.*]/_/g; s/__/_/g; s/_-_/-/; s/^_//g;p' | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]').pem; echo "${newname}"; mv "${cert}" "${newname}"; done```

Comment: the issue is that it downloads all except root CA cert.

Comment: @kensai as previously mentioned, that should not be the case. The server might not be sending it though, as it makes little sense. See [RFC 5246 - TLS v1.2, sec. 7.4.2. - Server Certificate](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246#section-7.4.2)

Comment: [WARNING] ubuntu certificate store only reads `.crt` files, so name your certs with that file extension instead of `.pem`, if you want to import them in the system store

Answer (score 6):

I found out that with the option `-verify 5` openssl is going deep in the chain showing all the cert, even that not included in your certificate deployment.

If you really want to understand which chain is provided with your certificate you should run:

```
openssl s_client -showcerts -partial_chain -connect YOUR_ENDPOINT:443 < /dev/null |less
```

Comment: `unknown option -partial_chain`

Answer (score 4):

I also had the same challenge and next to that I discovered that openssl doesn't return the root ca. I have built an alternative for specifically for this purpose which might be useful for other developers, see here: [GitHub - Certificate ripper](https://github.com/Hakky54/certificate-ripper)

**Usage**

- Printing to the console

```
crip print --url=https://stackexchange.com --format=pem
```

- Exporting to a p12 trustore

```
crip export p12 --url=https://stackexchange.com
```

The `p12` option can be replaced for `pem` or `der` if you want a different output.

Comment: yes agreed I tried other answers but they didn't return root certificate

Answer (score 2):

The above failed to work for me when I was using a Lets Encrypt Free Wildcard Certificate.

To be more specific:
I have a Kubernetes Cluster + Ingress Controller that's configured using a Lets Encrypt Free Wildcard Certificate for *.mydomain.dev, it's hosting the following 2 domain names:

- grafana.mydomain.dev
- prometheus.mydomain.dev

I had to add the -servername flag following per this site: https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/where-can-i-download-the-trusted-root-ca-certificates-for-lets-encrypt/33241/2

`export DOMAIN=grafana.mydomain.dev`
`openssl s_client -showcerts -verify 5 -connect $DOMAIN:443 -servername $DOMAIN < /dev/null 2> /dev/null | awk '/BEGIN/,/END/{ if(/BEGIN/){a++}; print}'`

I also tweaked the chain so it gives me the full cert + intermediate + root to standard output & hide stderr noise.

Actually... When testing I found out this doesn't give me the CA...
`openssl s_client -showcerts -verify 5 -connect letsencrypt.org:443 < /dev/null 2> /dev/null | awk '/BEGIN/,/END/{ if(/BEGIN/){a++}; print}'`

`curl https://letsencrypt.org/certs/isrgrootx1.pem`
Gives a different value (and when testing some stuff this is the value that works.)